# GCC linaro compiler throws error "unknown type name size_t"

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, size-t, linaro

I am using [GCC Linaro](http://releases.linaro.org/14.07/components/toolchain/binaries) compiler for compiling my code. Its throwing the error `unknown type name size_t` from `libio.h`. Its included from `stdio.h`. In my code I am just including `stdio.h`.

Can any one please how to resolve this error.

Comment: Show your code. We can't help without seeing your code.

Comment: If `size_t not found` error is from my code means, I would have done `#define size_t unsigned long` for compiling temporarily. But this error is from this system header file `libio.h` which is present inside this compiler.

Comment: You could also get the preprocessed form with `gcc -Wall -C -E` and compile with `gcc -Wall -g -H` to get the included headers. And `libio.h` is very probably not a compiler-specific header (but a `libc` specific one)

Comment: @raja ashok I would never use a #define where a typedef could be used.

Comment: I hadn't heard of `libio.h`. It exists on my system, with `#warning "<libio.h> is deprecated; use <stdio.h> instead."`. Don't use it.

Answer (score 60):

As per C99, §7.17, `size_t` is not a builtin type but defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Including the `<stddef.h>` header should fix your problem.

Comment: It's also defined in `<stdio.h>`, and in several other standard headers. The question doesn't give us enough information to determine why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, I had this exact same problem with a QT project, where I was using a Linaro compiler to (on both x86 Windows and x86 Linux) build for ARM Linux.  Using the exact same code and .pro file, I had no problems building on Windows, but I had a litany of errors building on the Linux box, beginning with the `unknown type name 'size_t'` in `libio.h` which traced back to a `#include <stdio.h>`.  I looked in the `stdio.h` (in the sysroot for the target hardware, not on the host machine), and a few lines down was `#include <stddef.h>` (much before `#include <libio.h>`), so `stddef.h` was definitely getting included.  However, upon further inspection, `stddef.h` was completely empty with a file size of 1 byte.  This was true for `stddef.h` in my sysroot and on my host machine.  I have no idea why these files were empty.

Anyway, turns out I had an extraneous `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/linux` in my .pro file.  On my Linux build machine, this added `-I/usr/include/linux` to the Makefile generated by qmake.  On my Windows build machine, this added `-isystem /usr/include/linux` to the Makefile generated by qmake.  Once I commented this out, these lines were removed from the Makefiles and it built right up on both build machines.  `-isystem /usr/include/linux` apparently never caused any trouble on the Windows build machine, so there was no harm in removing `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/linux`.

I don't really know why this fixed my problem, but I suspect it was some kind of conflict between header files.  Perhaps it was mixing host header files with sysroot header files, or creating a circular dependency somehow.  GCC documentation says that anything included with the `-I` option will take precedence over a system header file.  My best advice for this problem is to take a hard look at exactly which header files are being included and where they are coming from.

Comment: I was just building ffmpeg, and, trying to get a certain header file to be recognized, I added /usr/include/linux to the include dirs. Later on I had the above problem, and via your answer, removing /usr/include/linux (and using a more proper directory for the needed headers) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` include the data type `size_t`. They include this data type because the functions declared in these headers either take `size_t` as a parameter, or return it as a return type. `size_t` itself is a `typedef` to an unsigned integral type and it's also returned by the `sizeof` operator.

And because the `sizeof` operator is built into the C Programming Language itself, not included via some library, then how can `size_t` be an unknown type name?

Comment: The `sizeof` operator yields a result of some implementation-defined unsigned integer type. The name `size_t` for that type is defined in several standard headers, and is not visible unless at least one of those headers is included. Your answer tries to explain why the problem the OP is asking about can't occur, so you're not answering the question.