# gcc compilation: size_t not found (installing JLirc on 64 bit system)

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface, lirc

I'm using JLirc to access my remote control in java. It uses a native method to connect to lirc through a socket. Unfortunately, the last update of JLirc was 15 years ago, so it has no support for 64 bit systems.

I therefore turned to JUDS, which should be able to give me another way to create a socket to connect to lirc.

I use what I think is standard C methods to compile the library accessed through java (`libunixdomainsocket-linux-x86_64.so`). I created the config file using`autoconf` and the makefile using `./configure`.

If I now run `make`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/javah -sourcepath . -o com/etsy/net/UnixDomainSocket.h com.etsy.net.UnixDomainSocket
gcc -g -O2 -shared -fPIC -I /usr/include -I /usr/include/linux -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -m32 -o libunixdomainsocket-linux-i386.so com/etsy/net/UnixDomainSocket.c 
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h:39,
                 from com/etsy/net/UnixDomainSocket.h:2,
                 from com/etsy/net/UnixDomainSocket.c:6:
/usr/include/libio.h:306:3: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
   size_t __pad5;
```

I read [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410466/gcc-linaro-compiler-throws-error-unknown-type-name-size-t) that including `<stddef.h>` would help. However, adding the line `#include <stddef.h>` in the .c source file that it tries to compile doesn't help.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

- Find a way to compile JUDS and get my .so file
- Find another way than JUDS to connect to a linux socket in java
- find another way than JLirc to connect to lirc through java

Comment: Did you add the include of `<stddef.h>` at the top of the `.c` file? If so, try `<unistd.h>` instead.

Comment: Since you are already using Autoconf anyway, you should have it figure out how to get `size_t` by using its [`AC_TYPE_SIZE_T`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Particular-Types) macro.

Comment: You *might* be able to get away with a preprocessor macro (`-Dsize_t=int`), but if there are many other compile errors you're likely better off fixing the `autoconf` operation.