# unknown type name size_t

Tags: c, sdk, size-t

I use `/usr/include/bits/libio.h` file in a SDK program as a external location file. I get the error `unknown type name size_t` in this file (and a lot of errors derived from this). This file includes the `stddef.h`, so I don't know if something else is needed or why this error could be appearing. Coud someone help me with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410466/gcc-linaro-compiler-throws-error-unknown-type-name-size-t) has the exact same problem and likewise doesn't give enough information about why the compiler is complaining. Could you provide it, please?

Comment: #include <stdint.h>

Comment: @Devolus No. You need to include `stddef.h` or `stdio.h`.

Comment: Sara Alonso, Try adding `#include <stddef.h>` and  `#include <stdlib.h>` before `/usr/include/bits/libio.h` and report the result.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to include bits/libio.h directly.  It's not supported.  Include `<stdio.h>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include `libio.h`. Use `stdio.h` instead.

`libio.h` is included internally by the `stdio.h` in many `glibc` implementations.